# How convert TCP socket received data in integer using python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tcp, tcpclient

I am working on a python program to receive data from TCP socket. I am successfully able to receive the data in ASCII format. Now I want to view the received values in user readable format or in integer format. How to convert these values in integer form and plot a 3D graph from the received values.
Following are the continuous data I am receiving:

**Output**

```
received "['0216', '0212', '0211', '020B', '0214', '020E', '0211', '0210', '0206', '0208', '0206', '0207', '0200', '0208', '0203', '0000', '0200', '0000', '0200', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '01FE', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0203', '01FF', '0202', '01FF', '0203', '0202', '0207', '0205', '0207', '0213', '0209', '020C', '0212', '021A', '0217\x17']"
received "['0212', '0210', '0212', '020D', '020D', '020C', '020F', '0206', '020B', '020B', '0204', '0205', '0201', '0000', '0201', '01FE', '01FE', '0000', '01FE', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0200', '0200', '0200', '01FC', '0000', '0202', '0201', '01FE', '0209', '0207', '0208', '020B', '020A', '020B', '020C', '0212']"
...................................................
```

Please help me in the below code to show these received values to show as an integer and plotting an active 3D graph from from these received values.

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function

import socket
import sys
import time
from time import sleep

start = time.time()
def comm_dists(ip, port):

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = (ip, port)
    print(sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
    sock.connect(server_address)
    print("Connected")
    try:

        # Send data
        message = b'\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x10sMI 0 3 F4724744 '
        sock.sendall(message)
        print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message)
        print('sent "%s"' % message)
        data = sock.recv(5000)
        print(sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data)
        sleep(0.05)
        message = b"\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06sMI 5E'"
        sock.sendall(message)
        print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message)
        print('sent "%s"' % message)
        data = sock.recv(5000)
        print(sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data)
        sleep(0.05)
        message = b'\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05sMI 2e'
        sock.sendall(message)
        print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message)
        print('sent "%s"' % message)
        data = sock.recv(5000)
        print(sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data)
        sleep(0.05)
        message = b'\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x07sEI A 1\x0f'
        sock.sendall(message)
        print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message)
        print('sent "%s"' % message)
        data = sock.recv(5000)
        print(sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data)
        sleep(0.05)
        message = b'\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06sRI C5>'
        sock.sendall(message)
        print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message)
        print('sent "%s"' % message)
        data = sock.recv(5000)
        print(sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data)
        sleep(0.05)
        n = 52
        while True:
            data = sock.recv(5000)
            data = data.decode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
            data = data.replace('\x02', '')
            data = data.replace('\x00', '')
            data = data.replace('\x05', '')
            data = data.replace('sRA', '')
            data = data.replace('sSI', '') #comandAns
            data = data.replace('000A', '') #distResolution
            data = data.replace('425C0000', '') #startAngle
            data = data.replace('3E800000', '')
            data = data.replace('0118', '')  #angularStep
            data = data.split()
            print('received "%s"' %data)

    finally:
        print(sys.stderr, 'closing socket')
    return data

i=0
while i < int(1):
    data = comm_dists('192.168.0.1', 2111)
    i=i+1
```

**Result expected:**

1. Display the received output as an integer.
2. Plot a 3D graph from the received coordinate of the socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're receiving a list, with a list comprehension you should get the integeres like this:

```
integer_data = [int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex(item[0:3]), 'big') for item in data[:-2]]
```

This other decoding is for little endian encoding of your data:

```
integer_data = [int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex(item[0:3]), 'little') for item in data[:-2]]
```

This will preserve your data structure and convert everything in integer, keep in mind that this is not a very efficient way to deal with this problem, because you could send the integers in the first place from the other end!

Comment: I am receiving the following error:

 ```
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/LaserRec.py", line 77, in comm_dists integer_data = [int(item) for item in data]
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/LaserRec.py", line 77, in <listcomp> integer_data = [int(item) for item in data]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '00C5'
```

Comment: Oh your information is encoded in hexadecimal, let me edit the answer, hex does the trick

Comment: Now after applying the above solution, **hex_data = [hex(item) for item in data]** receiving the following error: 
`hex_data = [hex(item) for item in data]
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer `

Comment: Now it should work, but keep in mind that you have some broken data like for example the last entry of the list contains '0217\x17'] which seems not a valid integer.

Comment: Yes,_some broken data like '0217\x17'] is creating a serious issue. It is showing error:  **ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 5** Is there a solution so, that I can exclude the last two entry?

Comment: You can keep just the first 4 chars for every data you get, I edied the answer

Comment: @critian. Thank for your so much support. But, now after implementing the edited suggestion, it is showing the following Error: **ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 3**. Suppose, I want to replace the last  2 entries of the list. How I can do this?

Comment: Edit made to the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your generous help. I have one more serious issue. can you please hep in in resolving the below issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374727/how-to-plot-a-realtime-3d-graph-from-tcp-socket-received-data-in-integer-using-p
I want to plot an active 3D plot graph from these received values.